# Restricting cell to enter only numeric values in ngHandsontable

Tags: angularjs

How can I restrict user to enter only numeric values in cell in [ngHandsontable](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable)?

Comment: you can set the `type` to `numeric`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the `type` to `numeric`. Also, you can set a validation using `validator` property.

```
columns:[
   {
      data: 'level',
      type: 'numeric', /* or */
      validator: new RegExp('^\\d+$')
   }
]
```

Comment: Can I get to know how can I use validator tag in HTML?

Comment: You have to use it in JS.